# Strapi - How to custom graphql with Strapi

Tags: graphql, strapi

Ex:
http://localhost:1337/graphql?query={users(id:1){id}}
expect:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

actual:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"id\" on field \"users\" of type \"Schema\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 8
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using strapi v3.0.0-alpha.12.4
you should specify "where" parameter to filter data.

In your case it should be:

```
http://localhost:1337/graphql?query={users(where:{id:1}){id}}
```

From the official documentation (https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/graphql.html):

> You can also apply different parameters to the query to make more complex queries.
>
> limit (integer): Define the number of returned entries.
>
> start (integer): Define the amount of entries to skip.
>
> sort (string): Define how the data should be sorted.
>
> where (object): Define the filters to apply in the query.
>
> : Equals.
>
> _ne: Not equals.
>
> _lt: Lower than.
>
> _lte: Lower than or equal to.
>
> _gt: Greater than.
>
> _gte: Lower than or equal to.
>
> _contains: Contains.
>
> _containss: Contains sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to query `_id` and not `id`